# How to customize the method of fitting to a specific one?

Tags: fitting

I have a set of data as follows

```
denvals={{1.*10^-10, 0.0810057333956}, {0.1000000001, 
  0.0803383352917}, {0.2000000001, 0.0783764221896}, {0.3000000001, 
  0.0752361768031}, {0.4000000001, 0.0710965306337}, {0.5000000001, 
  0.0661798069267}, {0.6000000001, 0.0607293597458}, {0.7000000001, 
  0.0549876013364}, {0.8000000001, 0.0491773101952}, {0.9000000001, 
  0.043488126848}, {1.0000000001, 0.0380689715157}, {1.1000000001, 
  0.0330260484131}, {1.2000000001, 0.0284253395221}, {1.3000000001, 
  0.0242981180974}, {1.4000000001, 0.0206479977403}, {1.5000000001, 
  0.017458272451}, {1.6000000001, 0.0146986684367}, {1.7000000001, 
  0.0123310073303}, {1.8000000001, 0.0103135982483}, {1.9000000001, 
  0.00860439945034}, {2.0000000001, 0.00716311851782}, {2.1000000001, 
  0.00595247137122}, {2.2000000001, 0.00493882018363}, {2.3000000001, 
  0.00409238165254}, {2.4000000001, 0.0033871576382}, {2.5000000001, 
  0.00280070078}, {2.6000000001, 0.00231379384748}, {2.7000000001, 
  0.00191009507058}, {2.8000000001, 0.00157578225261}, {2.9000000001, 
  0.0012992149151}, {3.0000000001, 0.00107062466419}, {3.1000000001, 
  0.000881838143915}, {3.2000000001, 
  0.000726033350367}, {3.3000000001, 
  0.000597527981913}, {3.4000000001, 
  0.000491597371422}, {3.5000000001, 
  0.000404319032004}, {3.6000000001, 
  0.000332440710482}, {3.7000000001, 
  0.000273268927791}, {3.8000000001, 
  0.000224575192768}, {3.9000000001, 
  0.000184517342122}, {4.0000000001, 
  0.000151573745592}, {4.1000000001, 
  0.000124488398154}, {4.2000000001, 
  0.000102225187259}, {4.3000000001, 
  0.000083929865883}, {4.4000000001, 
  0.0000688984789034}, {4.5000000001, 
  0.000056551180804}, {4.6000000001, 
  0.0000464105481612}, {4.7000000001, 
  0.0000380836328101}, {4.8000000001, 
  0.0000312471233147}, {4.9000000001, 
  0.0000256350858143}, {5.0000000001, 
  0.0000210288428147}, {5.1000000001, 
  0.0000172486222052}, {5.2000000001, 
  0.0000141466706929}, {5.3000000001, 
  0.0000116015776872}, {5.4000000001, 
  9.51359898743*10^-6}, {5.5000000001, 
  7.80080574741*10^-6}, {5.6000000001, 
  6.39591425739*10^-6}, {5.7000000001, 
  5.24367707465*10^-6}, {5.8000000001, 
  4.2987367769*10^-6}, {5.9000000001, 
  3.52386081046*10^-6}, {6.0000000001, 
  2.88849014888*10^-6}, {6.1000000001, 
  2.36754626356*10^-6}, {6.2000000001, 
  1.94045065308*10^-6}, {6.3000000001, 
  1.59031922862*10^-6}, {6.4000000001, 
  1.30330050031*10^-6}, {6.5000000001, 
  1.06803199449*10^-6}, {6.6000000001, 
  8.75193855239*10^-7}, {6.7000000001, 
  7.17142312901*10^-7}, {6.8000000001, 
  5.8760877423*10^-7}, {6.9000000001, 
  4.81452819744*10^-7}, {7.0000000001, 
  3.94459477053*10^-7}, {7.1000000001, 
  3.23172853705*10^-7}, {7.2000000001, 
  2.64759623953*10^-7}, {7.3000000001, 
  2.16897024296*10^-7}, {7.4000000001, 
  1.77680966929*10^-7}, {7.5000000001, 
  1.4555066481*10^-7}, {7.6000000001, 
  1.19226806861*10^-7}, {7.7000000001, 
  9.7660851735*10^-8}, {7.8000000001, 
  7.99934439826*10^-8}, {7.9000000001, 
  6.55203140488*10^-8}, {8.0000000001, 
  5.36643172938*10^-8}, {8.1000000001, 
  4.39525084245*10^-8}, {8.2000000001, 
  3.59973457718*10^-8}, {8.3000000001, 
  2.9481282433*10^-8}, {8.4000000001, 
  2.41441347507*10^-8}, {8.5000000001, 
  1.97727281303*10^-8}, {8.6000000001, 
  1.61924100831*10^-8}, {8.7000000001, 
  1.3260094134*10^-8}, {8.8000000001, 
  1.0858558749*10^-8}, {8.9000000001, 
  8.89177507632*10^-9}, {9.0000000001, 
  7.28107802043*10^-9}, {9.1000000001, 
  5.96202856982*10^-9}, {9.2000000001, 
  4.88184269326*10^-9}, {9.3000000001, 
  3.99728458662*10^-9}, {9.4000000001, 
  3.2729404756*10^-9}, {9.5000000001, 
  2.67980428642*10^-9}, {9.6000000001, 
  2.19411888286*10^-9}, {9.7000000001, 
  1.79642672313*10^-9}, {9.8000000001, 
  1.47079211573*10^-9}, {9.9000000001, 1.20416407783*10^-9}}
```

I fit this data set to a gaussian function as follows

```
fit1 = NonlinearModelFit[dataset, {a1*Exp[-b1*(x)^2]}, {a1, b1}, x, 
   Method -> NMinimize];
```

and this is the result which I get

```
res[y_] := Normal[fit1] /. x -> y;
SetPrecision[res[y], 10]
(*0.07925484141 2.718281828^(-0.6882650854 y^2)*)
```

but when I calculate the percentage errors as follows

```
resfit = SetPrecision[
  Table[{denvals[[i, 1]], 
    Abs[(res[denvals[[i, 1]]] - denvals[[i, 2]])/
      denvals[[i, 2]]]*100}, {i, Length[denvals]}], 10];
```

and plot them

```
ListPlot[Table[Transpose[{resfit[[i, 1]], resfit[[i, 2]]}], {i, 100}]]
```

I get
[image]
which shows the ditribution of percentage errors is not the same (errors tend to 100 in far y's) this while I need some fitting result which produces a same distribution of percentage errors (where the above plot becomes a horizontal line). Can someone tell me how to do such a fitting? Is there an option for `NonlinearModelFit` or other fitting commands to include such a condition?

**My main question: How can I impose a condition to a fitting? (here this condition is homogeneous distribution of percentage errors as I explained above)**

Comment: I assume that `denvals` is the same as `dataset` but you should edit your question with the desired name choice.  And the "distribution of percentage errors is not the same":  not the same as what?

Comment: @JimB  Thanks, I corrected the question. Please see the bold text in the end of question for more clarity.

Comment: If you had a better fitting model and the error structure was such that the percentage error was relatively constant across predicted values and across the values of the predictor variable, then you'd have a multiplicative error which would require fitting the log of the response variable (which turns the multiplicative error to an additive error and then `NonlinearModelFit` would be appropriate).

Comment: You could use weights to tell NonLinearModelFit that not all data points have the same error bars. The points with larger x-values clearly have lower variance.

Comment: As others have pointed out, your model doesn't really fit the data (Side note: you mention the data come from an "analytical formula" - why do you want to fit the result in that case?). If you do want to fit the data, consider another model, e.g. $a\cdot\mathrm{sech}(bx)^c$ appears to fit quite nicely: `ResourceFunction["FittedModelPlot"][denvals, a*Sech[b*x]^c, {a,b,c}, x, ScalingFunctions->"Log", LegendFunction->Identity, PlotRange->All]` (although the residuals still show a systematic error)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the fit looks pretty good:

```
Show[Plot[fit1[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[dataset, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

But your percent error suggests otherwise... let's look at the Log to see what's happening:

```
Show[Plot[Log[fit1[x]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[Transpose[{dataset[[All, 1]], Log[dataset[[All, 2]]]}], PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

So in the Log space you can see what's happening... the log data is decaying like a straight line but the log Gaussian decays like a quadratic. So one possibility would be to try fitting with something that decays like Exp[-x] (instead of a Gaussian). For example:

```
fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[dataset, {a1*Exp[-b1*Abs[x]]}, {a1, b1}, x, Method -> NMinimize];
```

gives a fit that looks like this:

[image]

It's still not perfect though. Alternatively, you could do the fit directly in the Log space -- this would make the percent error converge for large values, though likely would look a lot worse for small values.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I look for! Please see my main question which I added to the end of question as a bold text right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an extended comment.

I deal with biological data so I'm always skeptical when I see plots of data that seem to show very little variability and when there is no description as to how the data was collected.  I say that upfront to make you aware of my biases.

Your data just doesn't fit the proposed curve *AND* the equal-variance assumptions of `NonlinearModelFit` are not even close to being satisfied.  (It's not just about the fit "looking OK".)

While you've looked at a "percentage prediction error" that's not what `NonlinearModelFit` is using to find the best (although possibly inadequate) fit.  The plot you show can be obtained without all of the functions you've defined:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{dataset[[All, 1]], 100 Abs[fit1["FitResiduals"]/dataset[[All, 2]]]}]]
```

[image: Percentage errors]

The adequacy of the error structure assumed by `NonlinearModelFit` is better assessed with the following assessments of the residuals:

```
fit1 = NonlinearModelFit[dataset, {a1*Exp[-b1*(x)^2]}, {a1, b1}, x, Method -> NMinimize];

ListPlot[Transpose[{fit1["PredictedResponse"], fit1["FitResiduals"]}],
 AxesLabel -> {"Predicted response", "Residual"}]
```

[image: Predicted response vs residuals]
ListPlot[Transpose[{dataset[[All, 1]], fit1["FitResiduals"]}],
AxesLabel -> {"Response", "Residual"}]
[image: Response vs residual]
Histogram[fit1["FitResiduals"], "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF",
PlotLabel -> "Histogram of residuals"]
[image: Histogram of responses]

Fitting a linear function for the log of the response variable still shows a great deal of lack of fit.

```
logdata = dataset;
logdata[[All, 2]] = Log[logdata[[All, 2]]];
fit2 = LinearModelFit[logdata, x, x];
Show[ListPlot[logdata], 
 Plot[fit2[x], {x, Min[logdata[[All, 1]]], Max[logdata[[All, 1]]]}]]
```

[image: Linear fit]

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{fit2["PredictedResponse"], fit2["FitResiduals"]}],
 AxesLabel -> {"Predicted response", "Residual"}]
```

[image: Predicted response vs residual]

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{logdata[[All, 1]], fit2["FitResiduals"]}],
 AxesLabel -> {"Response", "Residual"}]
```

[image: Response vs residual]

```
Histogram[fit2["FitResiduals"], "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF",
 PlotLabel -> "Histogram of residuals"]
```

[image: Histogram of residuals]

In short, the underlying curve seems more complicated than the model considered.  Is there some theoretical reason for the model you chose?  If so, then what is needed is an explanation as to why the data doesn't fit that model.  That requires looking at how the data was collected.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is not the answer of my question. These data have been obtained from an analytical formula so they are correct. I'm sure that these data must be fitted to a gaussian function, because I know their asymptotic behavior is a gaussian function. However I want some option which imposes constant  relative percentage error to fit procedure.

Comment: We certainly took our statistics classes at different locations.

Comment: @Wisdom I can tell you from one glance that these data do not follow a Gaussian curve. That's immediately obvious on a logplot.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is define your own function to minimize that considers both the distribution of residuals as well as the magnitude of residuals and then use NMinimize to find a minimum of that function.

Here is an example where we are minimizing the sum of the standard deviation of residuals and the MAE of residuals:

```
fit=NMinimize[StandardDeviation[((a1*Exp[-b1*(Transpose[dataset][[1]])^2]-Transpose[dataset][[2]]))]+Mean[Abs[((a1*Exp[-b1*(Transpose[dataset][[1]])^2]-Transpose[dataset][[2]]))]],{a1,b1}]
```

You could play around with different weights between the two parts or implements some other function entirely to help fit your needs. With this example we can see that defining our own function to minimize changed the residual plot. The distribution still isn't very uniform but given the data and model form you are trying to fit, I'm not convinced it will be possible. Since your question seems to be more around how you would go about minimizing residuals with consideration given to the residual distribution I figured this answer is relevant despite it not yielding a model with a good fit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks however I'm not looking for minimizing the relative percentage errors but constant ones. How can I include such a condition to the fit procedure?

Comment: If you don’t want to reduce the relative percent errors you would just not divide by the actual response values. I updated the answer so it is not longer relative.